# Change latin numbers to arabic number by javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a clock with javascript i want change  latin numbers this clock to arabic number by javascript, i tried as following code, but it doesn't work true. How can fix it?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/NdzHg/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var interval = self.setInterval("clock()", 1000);
    function clock() {
    var rep = {
        '0': '&#1776;',
        '1': '&#1777;',
        '2': '&#1778;',
        '3': '&#1779;',
        '4': '&#1780;',
        '5': '&#1781;',
        '6': '&#1782;',
        '7': '&#1783;',
        '8': '&#1784;',
        '9': '&#1785;',
    }

        var date = new Date();
        var hourOffset = 4;
        date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes());
        var time = date.getTime();
        date.setUTCFullYear(date.getUTCFullYear(), 3, 21);
        var dstStart = date.getTime();
        date.setUTCFullYear(date.getUTCFullYear(), 9, 22);
        var dstEnd = date.getTime();
        if (time > dstStart && time < dstEnd){ hourOffset = 4;}
        date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours() + hourOffset, date.getUTCMinutes() + 30);
        var output = date.getUTCHours() + ":" + date.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + date.getUTCSeconds();
    for (key in rep) {
        str = output.split(key).join(rep[key]);
    }
        $("#clock").html(str);
    }
</script>
<div id="clock"></div>
​
```

Comment: What exactly "does not work"? What does it do and what is it supposed to do? If you just base your statement on the fact that your fiddle does not work, then please take your time to first [learn how jsfiddle works](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/). You have to set it up properly, for example your code uses jQuery but the fiddle is set up to use Mootools.

Comment: @Felix Kling - Time does not display

Comment: If I set up the fiddle correctly, it does. Please read it's documentation. Of course there might be other problems, like accessing an element before it exists, or passing a string to `setTimeout`, but these have already been covered, you just have to search.

Comment: I updated ur version to show at least the time and it work for only the 9 : http://jsfiddle.net/NdzHg/2/

Comment: @Tarek: It only works for `9` because `str` is overridden and the original output is used in each iteration. The logic is flawed but easy to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try that : http://jsfiddle.net/McxL5/  btw it's in mootools ...

Here is the jquery version : http://jsfiddle.net/McxL5/12/

Comment: Did should I use mootools? Can without it be done(I want done with jquery or just javascript no use mootools)?

Comment: Modified the answer to add the jquery version